# How to get exact sum of two or more rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have one problem and I'll describe it on trivial example.

I have table with data:

```
Id       DocNumb        Total
1         doc1            5
2         doc2            3
3         doc3           12
4         doc4            4
5         doc5           14
6         doc6           12
7         doc7            4
8         doc8           11
9         doc9            2
```

I want to write query to get rows which sum is 7.

It will be:

```
Id       DocNumb        Total
1         doc1            5
9         doc9            2
2         doc2            3
4         doc4            4
2         doc2            3
7         doc7            4
```

Comment: Do you want to include single-row cases as well? What about three or more rows adding up to 7?

Comment: If you add the row (10, doc10, 2), do you also expect doc2, doc9 and doc10 to be returned? (3+2+2=7)

Comment: No, I don't want to include single-row, but yes, I want to include more three or more rows. 

If I add the row (10, doc10, 2) must be returned 3+2+2=7

Answer (score 1):

You can get all pairs using a self-join:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id and  -- no need for duplicates
        t1.total + t2.total = 7;
```

This puts the results in a single row -- which makes more sense, so you know which pairs are adding up to `7`.

EDIT:

You can add additional `join`s if you want more rows:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id and  -- no need for duplicates left join
     t t3
     on t2.id < t3.id
 where t1.total + t2.total + coalesce(t3.total, 0) = 7;
```

Because of the nature of your data -- the smallest value is "2" and you want the total to be "7" -- the maximum number of rows is 3.  So the above answers the question that you have asked.

A more general approach would use recursive CTEs.

Comment: This solution only return tuples of two rows, but not three or more.

Comment: I supposed that recursive CTEs is only solution.

Comment: @Haldir . . . It depends on the constraints in the problem, but that is the most reasonable general approach.